# List of dictionaries, remove dicts with some duplicate key, values

Tags: python

Removing duplicates from list of dicts is as simple as set(list) but i have got stuck with this specific task.

I need to filter a list of dicts only by some keys and keep only the first elements

```
flights = [
    {
        'dep_code': 'LON',
        'arr_code': 'PAR',
        'airline': 'BA',
        'date': '2022-07-07'
    },
    {
        'dep_code': 'LON',
        'arr_code': 'PAR',
        'airline': 'BA',
        'date': '2022-08-07'
    },
    {
        'dep_code': 'LON',
        'arr_code': 'PAR',
        'airline': 'BA',
        'date': '2022-09-07'
    },
    {
        'dep_code': 'LON',
        'arr_code': 'BRU',
        'airline': 'BA',
        'date': '2022-10-07'
    },
    {
        'dep_code': 'LON',
        'arr_code': 'BRU',
        'airline': 'BA',
        'date': '2022-11-07'
    },
]
```

I need to get this very result (keep only first elements with same 'dep_code' and 'arr_code')

```
flights = [
    {
        'dep_code': 'LON',
        'arr_code': 'PAR',
        'airline': 'BA',
        'date': '2022-07-07'
    },
    {
        'dep_code': 'LON',
        'arr_code': 'BRU',
        'airline': 'BA',
        'date': '2022-10-07'
    },
]
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you haven't yet, you need to make an honest attempt at solving the problem yourself before asking here. If you've tried something already that didn't work, share that as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask a specific question about the problem you ran into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save all found data in a list.

```
found = list()
result = list()
for d in flights:
    if not [d['dep_code'],d['arr_code']] in found:
        result.append(d)
        found.append([d['dep_code'],d['arr_code']])
print(result)
```

Comment: I was hoping there is some shorter magic for this task but this naive method also works, thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are shorter versions, but I personally prefer these because they are easier to understand and you can modify it if you understand it. Even if you have a one liner, if you dont understand it and you want to modify your code it would only make the your work longer

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using pandas, you could use it to filter the values:

```
import pandas as pd

out = pd.DataFrame(flights).drop_duplicates(subset=['dep_code', 'arr_code'], keep='first').to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
[
 {'dep_code': 'LON', 'arr_code': 'PAR', 'airline': 'BA', 'date': '2022-07-07'},
 {'dep_code': 'LON', 'arr_code': 'BRU', 'airline': 'BA', 'date': '2022-10-07'}
]
```

Comment: I cannot use library for this, but thanks for input

Comment: Pandas is a pretty huge library, it seems overkill to use it for this, it will make you waste a lot of resources

Comment: @MariusROBERT agreed, but if OP is already using pandas for other functionality then there's no additional cost.

Comment: @MariusROBERT I've made a note to that effect

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby` for this.

```py
from itertools import groupby

def unique(lst):
    for _, group in groupby(lst, lambda dic: (dic['dep_code'], dic['arr_code'])):
        yield list(group)[0]

print(list(unique(flights)))
```

Ouptut:

```
[{'dep_code': 'LON', 'arr_code': 'PAR', 'airline': 'BA', 'date': '2022-07-07'}, {'dep_code': 'LON', 'arr_code': 'BRU', 'airline': 'BA', 'date': '2022-10-07'}]
```

Comment: This one is good and shortest, but for me as a beginner is easier to stick to naive methods. Thanks